# Change UICollectionViewCell content and nib layout based on data

Tags: iphone, ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionView that is displaying many UICollectionViewCells that I have subclassed as CardCell. I pass the variable "type" to the CardCell in `- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` I want the CardCell class to be able to load a different Nib file depending on what type is passed in. The different types need to have different layouts.

The problem is I cannot figure out where to change this in my CardCell.m. I tried using `- (void)prepareForReuse` but that does not call unless the user is scrolling.

Comment: You can't figure out where to change what?

Comment: Change which nib file is loaded for the cell

Comment: Have you tried using different cell identifiers? You could register different nibs for different identifiers, then dequeue the proper cell from `cellForItemAtIndexPath`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should register each nib file you need in viewDidLoad, something like this (substituting the correct names for the nib file and the identifier):

```
[self.collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"RDCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"FirstType"];
```

Then, in itemForRowAtIndexPath, test for type and return the correct type of cell:

```
 - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        if (type = @"firstType") {
            FirstCell *cell = (FirstCell *) [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"FirstType" forIndexPath:indexPath];
            return cell;
        }else{
            SecondCell *cell = (SecondCell *) [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"SecondType" forIndexPath:indexPath];
            cell.whatever .....
            return cell;
        }
}
```

Comment: You have a scope issue here. cell is not defined outside of your if statements and so cell will not be defined when you go to return outside of any of the if/else statements.

Comment: @JeremyHicks, when you  register a nib, dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath: is guaranteed to return a cell, so there's no need for the traditional if(cell==nil) clause.

Comment: But that cell is getting created inside the if/else statement so the return call must also exist inside the if/else statement. Is that not correct? I can't get it to work any other way when dealing with cells that are of different classes.

Comment: @JeremyHicks, yes you're right, I misunderstood your comment. The return cell line should be in each clause. I have edited my answer to be correct. Thanks for the heads up.