# Calling two different custom cell in one UITableView issue

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, custom-cell

I have created a custom cell FeatureCell which has 5 images in the row that will be called in the main view but when I call it I get empty row. So please where could be my problem?

I have googled about custom cell and I used the way that I have to use in the code below but nothing happen.

This is my FeatureCell.h

```
@interface FeatureCell : UITableViewCell{

  IBOutlet UIImageView *img1;
  IBOutlet UIImageView *img2;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *img1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *img2;
@end
```

This is my FeatureCell.m

```
@implementation FeatureCell

@synthesize img,img1,img2,img3,img4;
@end
```

This is the my view-controller .m

```
- (NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{

return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

if (section == 0) {
    return [objectCollection count];
}
else{
    return 1;
   }
}    

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString* cellIdentifier1 = @"FeatureCell";

FeatureCell *cell1 = (FeatureCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier1];


if (cell1 == nil)
{
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:cellIdentifier1 owner:nil options:nil];

    cell1 = (FeatureCell*)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
}

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1
                                  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

}


if ([indexPath section] == 0) {

    containerObject = [objectCollection objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [[cell textLabel] setText:containerObject.store];

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

}
    else{

    cell1.img1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"shower.png"];
    cell1.img2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"parking.png"];

    }
        return cell;
}
```

Comment: Did you connect the outlets?

Comment: This is not the correct way to deal with 2 different cell types. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17711452/change-uicollectionviewcell-content-and-nib-layout-based-on-data/17711644#17711644. This deals with collection views, but it's the same with table views.

Comment: @Wain what do you mean by outlets?

Comment: @rdelmar I am not using collection views. Is the custom cell and collection views is the same?

Comment: You are only returning 'cell'. What about 'cell1'?

Comment: @rocky I missed the return of cell1 it works now thanks.

Comment: Yes, the api for table views and collection views are very similar, and the way you retrieve different cells (or items in a collection view) are the same.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to do something like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1
                              reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }

        containerObject = [objectCollection objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [[cell textLabel] setText:containerObject.store];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        return cell;
    } else {
        static NSString* cellIdentifier1 = @"FeatureCell";

        FeatureCell *cell1 = (FeatureCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier1];
        if (cell1 == nil) {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:cellIdentifier1 owner:nil options:nil];
            cell1 = (FeatureCell*)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }

        cell1.img1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"shower.png"];
        cell1.img2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"parking.png"];

        return cell1;
    }
}
```

I might have the `if` condition backwards so double check that.

Comment: cellForRowAtIndexPath needs to return an UITableViewCell instance. Your code will throw an error, because you're not returning anything outside the if-else statement.

Comment: @Sebyddd no it's fine.

Comment: Just tried it, 'Control may reach end of non-void function.' :)

Comment: @Sebyddd As long as there is a return in both the if part and the else part you won't get that compiler error.

Comment: I know what you're saying. It might be a bug in the compiler. It shouldn't throw this error.

Comment: @Sebyddd: No, you are wrong. There will be 01 return statement is called.

Answer (score 0):

This implementation:

```
@implementation FeatureCell
@synthesize img,img1,img2,img3,img4;
@end
```

Results in a cell with some accessor methods but no initialised instances. You need to implement an `init` method to create the instances or connect the variables (which you define as outlets) to the associated XIB file. Read [this guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_User_Guide/030-Edit_User_Interfaces/edit_user_interface.html).

I also agree with the comments about the structure of how you're creating your different cell instances. It's very disorganised and you seem to be mixing up references. You should split things out into different methods or at least put the code for creating the cells inside the `if` statements so you can't typo the cell instance names.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

{
   **if (indexPath.row == 0)**  //not indexPath.section...fixed my problem

```
{
   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MenuHeadingCustomCell";

   MenuHeadingCustomCell *cell =[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   if (cell ==nil)
   {
       cell = [[MenuHeadingCustomCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   }

   return cell;
}





else
   {
       static NSString* cellIdentifier1 = @"LevelViewCell";
       LevelViewCell *cell1 =[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier1];
       if (cell1 ==nil)
       {
           cell1 = [[LevelViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                      reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier1];

       // row counts which dictionary entry to load:
         _Dictionary=[_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

       cell1.LevelTitleText.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[_Dictionary objectForKey:@"LevelLabelText"]];
       cell1.LevelSubText.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[_Dictionary objectForKey:@"LevelLabelSubText"]];
       cell1.LevelThumb.image =[UIImage imageNamed:[_Dictionary objectForKey:@"LevelLabelThumb"]];

   }
   return cell1;

}
```